# how to update NSMutableArray data depending on id or based on position

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, updates

I have NSMutableArray data as below.

```
(
        {
        Id = 3;
        Name = Fahim;
    },
        {
        Id = 2;
        Name = milad;
    },
        {
        Id = 1;
        Name = Test;
    }
)
```

Now I want to update the name from Test to Omar (for id = 1).

Any idea how to get this done?

[image]

---

### Answer

With below answer, I was getting error as `-[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. To resolve that issue I  Changed `[feeds addObject:[item copy]]` to `[feeds addObject:item]`

Comment: Loop through the array, check if `array[i][@"Id"] == 1`, set `array[i][@"Name"]` accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for (NSMutableDictionary* aDict in yourMutableArray) {
    if (aDict[@"id"] == 1) {
        [aDict setObject:@"Omar" forKey:@"Name"];
    }
}
```

EDIT :

```
NSMutableArray* mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSDictionary* item1Dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"1",@"id",
                           @"Fahim",@"name"
                           , nil];

NSMutableDictionary* item1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:item1Dict];

[mutableArray addObject:item1];

NSDictionary* item2Dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"2",@"id",
                           @"milad",@"name"
                           , nil];

NSMutableDictionary* item2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:item2Dict];

[mutableArray addObject:item2];

NSDictionary* item3Dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"3",@"id",
                           @"test",@"name"
                           , nil];

NSMutableDictionary* item3 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:item3Dict];

[mutableArray addObject:item3];

NSLog(@"%@",mutableArray);

for (NSMutableDictionary* aDict in mutableArray) {
    if ([aDict[@"id"] isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
        [aDict setObject:@"Omar" forKey:@"name"];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@",mutableArray);
```

**And for much elegant:**

```
NSMutableArray* mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSArray* name = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Fahin",@"milad",@"test", nil];

for (int i = 0; i < name.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary* itemd = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i],@"id",
                               name[i],@"name"
                               , nil];

    NSMutableDictionary* item = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:itemd];
    //or
    //NSMutableDictionary* item = [item mutableCopy];
    [mutableArray addObject:item];
}

NSLog(@"%@",mutableArray);

for (NSMutableDictionary* aDict in mutableArray) {
    if ([aDict[@"id"] isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
        [aDict setObject:@"Omar" forKey:@"name"];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@",mutableArray);
```

logs are:

```
2013-10-18 00:51:48.845 test[34919:60b] (
        {
        id = 1;
        name = Fahim;
    },
        {
        id = 2;
        name = milad;
    },
        {
        id = 3;
        name = test;
    }
)
```

second log:

```
2013-10-18 00:52:06.887 test[34919:60b] (
        {
        id = 1;
        name = Fahim;
    },
        {
        id = 2;
        name = milad;
    },
        {
        id = 3;
        name = Omar;
    }
)
```

EDIT2 for copy:

-copy, as implemented by mutable Cocoa classes, always returns their immutable counterparts. When an NSMutableDictionary is sent -copy, it returns an NSDictionary containing the same objects. NSMutableDictionary is a subclass of NSDictionary, the compiler doesn't complain. NSDictionary does not recognize it's mutable subclass' methods (because it cannot mutate it's contents).

Comment: id is an int or string?

Comment: @incmiko Deducing from the description OP provided, it's a number.

Comment: Also, `[aDict setObject:]` will warn since `aDict` is declared to be an `NSDictionary`. Change its type to `NSMutableDictionary`. Furthermore, any particular reason you are not using the bracket notation for setting the value in the dictionary?

Comment: what if Id is string?

Comment: [aDict[@"id"] isEqualToString:@"1"]

Comment: I am getting error as `-[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: it can be because when you made your array, you added NSDictionaries to this array, not NSMutableDictionaries

Comment: its NSMutableDictionary... `item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`

Comment: @H2CO3 : any idea why I am getting error `-[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. I have it as NSMutableDictionary

Comment: I solved it by `[aDict mutableCopy]`, but still the Array is not getting updated...

Comment: checked... I tried and working also.. but I don't understand why I get error in mine code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39454/discussion-between-fahim-parkar-and-incmiko)

Comment: problem solved... changed `[feeds addObject:[item copy]]` to `[feeds addObject:item]`

Comment: I ve already started to write it. I m happy that your problem solved

Comment: why this `copy` was making problem?

Comment: @incmiko Why those `dictionaryWithDictionary:` calls? Why not `mutableCopy`?

Comment: Right, I'm never used mutableCopy, now I read about it, and yes it s can be better/sorter. I edited my answer. Thanks